# How to Expose Properties of a Control that is Inside a User Control?

Tags: wpf, xaml

For example, I have a button that is inside a User Control, and I would like to expose its own properties, so whenever somebody is using the User Control could easily change its button's properties values. I was actually able to accomplish this in two ways:

First, Bind the Button's property such as, FontSize to its equivalent in the UserControl:

```
<Button FontSize="{Binding Path=FontSize, ElementName=UserControl}" />
```

Second, Bind the Button's property to a new Dependency Property that is added to the User Control.

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=DependencyProperty, ElementName=UserControl}"
```

The question now, is there any way to access the Button's properties directly in XAML without doing any bindings to the User Control?

Comment: Give the button a name and use `ElementName` like you did with `UserControl`. I would suggest you read up on MVVM, because it will probably save you a lot of headaches binding to element names. It would become spaghetti faster then you can say bolgonese.

Comment: But then how will I use the ElementName of the button in XAML. For example, if the UserControl is dropped on the Canvas like <MyButton:ButtonUserControl />, where should the ButtonName fit here?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, but you shouldn't do that. You probably want to make a custom control. [Simple example](http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html)

Comment: Until now I thought that what I am doing is actually a Custom Control. I created this User Control externally as a WpfControlLibrary dll.

Comment: FYI, many properties, including `FontSize` should automatically be inherited by descendant controls.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, you are totally correct! However, how about properties such as the Content property. If I define this <MyButton:ButtonUserControl Content="Login" /> it will override the entire content of the User Control, which in this case is the Button Control. <UserControl> <Button /> </UserControl>

Comment: For those kinds of situations, you might want to declare a `ButtonContent` dependency property on your `UserControl`, and then bind to that.  Or just use MVVM.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, I don't get how MVVM will help in this situation. Silvermind mentioned MVVM as well. I wonder what particular part of the pattern should I looking at and will address this issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really desired to name `Controls` in WPF.
What you can do is use binding on the `Parent` using it's type rather than naming it.

```
<Button FontSize="{Binding FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                   AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
```

It's the easiest way.

Comment: Very good point. However, I wanted to stay away from binding. For example, if I wanted to expose all button's properties this means that I will have to bind every single one of them and maybe adding some additional Dependency Properties in case the User Control doesn't have equivalent ones. That is a lot of work.